# umount root in a script

Tags: shell-script, chroot

I'm writing a bash script to change my rootfs to another one, on a SD card.

The steps are roughly:

```
mount /dev/hda1 /new-root
cd /new-root
pivot_root . old-root
exec chroot . sh <dev/console >dev/console 2>&1
umount /old-root
```

This works as expected in an interactive mode but not in a script as the interpreters runs in the `old-root`, I cannot unmount it.

So, I tried using an intermediate script in which one I kill the parent like this:

```
# parent
exec chroot sd_card_fs sh -c script.sh

# son
cat script.sh
```

> ...
>   kill -9 $PPID
>   umount /old-root
>   ...

This doesn't work as the son suicides, killing its parent and I find this solution somehow dirty.

So my questions:

- Is there a cleaner way than invoking another script to do the job ? If not, how can I fix it ?

I really want to minimize, as much as possible the human interaction so calling a script, waiting for it to finish to launch another one is a no go unless there is no other solution.

Comment: Why exactly can't you umount, error message? Have you tried ```umount  -lf```. "lazy" umount should do what you want.

Comment: I cannot `umount` because the script runs in the old-root filesystem (therefore the error message is `can't umount /old-root: Device or resource busy`). Using `umount -lf` would work as soon as the script exits but I have some stuff to do after the `umount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But that last command in the "parent" script *replaces* it with the "son".  That's what `exec` does.  You should not have any parent process you could kill.

Such scripts can *only* work when the script is PID 1, so that there are no other processes[*].  **You must have booted with `init=/bin/bash`**.  **Remember to invoke your script by using `exec`**, so it replaces PID 1.

Do not use lazy unmount, it means you won't see error messages.

I'm 99% confident your lazy unmount hadn't finished.  I'm not sure how to test this, other than if you use ext4 or ext3, `file -s /dev/$ROOT_DEV` should show "needs journal recovery" (i.e. has not been cleanly unmounted).

I would expect your first attempt to work if you remove the `kill` and follow the bolded instructions above.  I might have missed something though.

---

[*] or, you would need to tell init to re-exec itself, after arranging for the path it exec's to be on the target filesystem.  But that sounds like a terrible idea to me.  Just keep things simple.